# Why is my screen turning blue?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

i have a samsung galaxy 3 and I dropped it and it cracked which has been fine. Just lately the top left corner has been turning blue and is spreading to the right side and lower what is it and what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

LCD is short for "liquid crystal display".  The liquid is leaking out due to the fractures.  Really the only thing you can do is to replace the screen.